# How to capture screenshot for Windows Phone 8.1 progmatically(c++)(Whole Screen)?

Tags: c++, screenshot, screen-capture, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 app. I need to capture whole screen. I have created a static lib project and accessing it with WinRT component. In the Lib project(c++), I am trying to use CreateCompatibleDC, BitBlt etc apis, but it seems they are not available in windows phone.

Please suggest any alternative or solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ScreenshotService` for this purpose.

Here is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/How-to-use-Cimbalino-749562db).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually in my requirement, I cannot use managed code. I mean, I need to do this(capturing screenshot) in my static lib project only. So are there any c or c++ apis which works on windows phone.